# Is basic authentication a token based authentication?

Tags: authentication, session, spring-security, authorization, token

I'm learning about authentication and authorization with Java and Spring Security and I see there are 2 types of authentication: session-based authentication and token-based authentication.

What about basic authentication?

Is this a token-based authentication or what kind of authentication is it?

Comment: No it's not. [Basic access authenticaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: Thank you for response! What about form based authentication? Is it a session based authentication or is defferent?

Answer (score 1):

A Basic Authentication takes in UserName and Password, and convert it to a base64 string. And then it is sent as a header with the key as **'Authorization'** and value as **'Basic <base64_encoded_username_password>'**.

**How is the base64 key generated, is as follows:**

```
UserName = test
Password = test
Basic auth string = (Username:Password) = (test:test) = dGVzdDp0ZXN0
```

Online generator - https://www.base64encode.org/

Then your header data will be -
**Authorization: Basic dGVzdDp0ZXN0**